# Ruby and money, in a rails app, how to store money values in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I want to make sure I don't have rounding issues when it comes to storing prices for products in a rails app.

What mysql datatype should I use, and what does it map to in rails?

I want decimal with 10 places for precision.

Comment: What does `10 places for precision` mean? 10 significant figures, 10 digits after the decimal, or something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds you want the `:decimal` column type.  You can control the total number of digits and the number of decimal places with the `:precision` and `:scale` options:

```
add_column :mytable, :mycolumn, :decimal, :precision => 30, :scale => 10
```

A little more on data types in [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).

Comment: For reference, there's a nice description of precision and scale in the first paragraph [here](https://millarian.com/rails/precision-and-scale-for-ruby-on-rails-migrations/).

Answer (score 16):

I prefer to store currency in the database as an integer of the lowest denomination (pence, cents etc), and do calculations against this.

```
add_column :product, :price, :integer
```

Of course, you will want any form input and display to be in the form people expect, so we add some helper methods to the model to help with this.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price_dollars
    self.price / 100
  end

  def price_dollars=(val)
    self.price = val * 100
  end
end
```

In the console we then get:

```
> prod = Product.new
=> [snip]

> prod.price_dollars = 12.93
=> 12.93
> prod.price
=> 1293
> prod.price_dollars
=> 12.93

> prod.price = 1691
=> 1691
> prod.price_dollars
=> 16.91
```

I'm sure there is probably a plugin that handles this nicely somewhere.

Comment: The plugin you're thinking of is the money gem, add `gem 'money'` to the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's always easiest to store your lowest common denominator as an integer in the database (here's a question where we used cents: [Handling international currency input in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669214/183497), but you could store prices in 1/10,000 cents if you like), and do the correct math when you take the number out of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Douglas's excellent answer above:

In order for it to work, at least in Ruby 2.1.4, you will need to convert the :price field to a float or decimal when dividing by 100.

Dividing an integer by another integer

**1293 / 100**

will not return what you might expect. Instead of getting **12.93** Ruby returns **12** the integer.

```
2.1.4 :002 > 1293 / 100
=> 12
2.1.4 :003 > 1293.to_f / 100
=> 12.93
```

Product Model Code Example

```html
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price_dollars
    self.price.to_f / 100
  end

  def price_dollars=(val)
    self.price = val * 100
  end
end
```

Answer (score -9):

Use "float"

```
add_column :customer, :amount, :float
```

Comment: float is not a precise data type that's for sure!

Comment: It's no more or less precise than decimal types, but since it's base-2, it's inappropriate for base-10 flavors of data that require roundtripping, like money.